# numpy busday_count for Days difference gives TypeError: dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate number of days between two dates and i get an error

`TypeError: ("Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'", 'occurred at index 0')`

The column REASSIGN_DATE has blank values in few rows which i am filling using another Column called SETUP_DATE to remove and blank values and fill a date.

Then i am trying to calculate the number days between these two days using the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import xlrd
import workdays
import defusedxml
from xlrd import open_workbook
defusedxml.defuse_stdlib()


def secure_open_workbook(**kwargs):
    try:
        return open_workbook(**kwargs)
    except EntitiesForbidden:
        raise ValueError('Please use a xlsx file without XEE')


#loading Raw Data
releases = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Desktop\Releases.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'Releases',
                     header = 0
                     )
releases.loc[releases['REASSIGN_DATE'].isnull(),'REASSIGN_DATE']=releases['SETUP_DATE']
releases['REASSIGN_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(releases['REASSIGN_DATE'])
releases['RELEASED_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(releases['RELEASED_DATE'])
releases['RELEASED_DAYS']=releases.apply(lambda x: 
np.busday_count(x.REASSIGN_DATE,x.RELEASED_DATE),axis =1)

releases_2=releases.drop(['SETUPDATE','RELEASEDDATE','REASSIGNDATE'],axis=1)
```

I get the error.

I even tried to add astype('datetime64[D]') as well however i get the error astype('datetime64[ns]') cannot be converted to astype('datetime64[D]').

How could i avoid this error.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy, TypeError: Could not be cast from dtype('<M8\[us\]') to dtype('<M8\[D\]')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435328/numpy-typeerror-could-not-be-cast-from-dtypem8us-to-dtypem8d)

Comment: As from the solution linked above, solution is to pass `date` instead of `datetime`