# get difference of two dates using np.busday_count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Let's say i have a dataframe like this:

```
     date_1         date_2
0  2022-08-01     2022-08-05
1  2022-08-20        NaN
2    NaN             NaN
```

I want to have another column which tells the difference in business days and have a dataframe like this (in case `date_2` is empty, it will be compared to today's date (`2022-08-28`)):

```
     date_1         date_2          diff
0  2022-08-01     2022-08-05          4
1  2022-08-20        NaN              5
2    NaN             NaN              Empty
```

I tried to use this one:

```
df["diff"] = df.apply(
lambda x: np.busday_count(x.date_1, x.date_2) if (x.date_1 != '' and x.date_2 != '') else (np.busday_count(x.date_1, np.datetime64('today')) if (x.date_1 != '' and x.date_2 == '') else ''), axis=1)
```

but im getting this error:

```
Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[us]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Any idea how to get the desired dataframe?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54435328/14627505

Comment: no, because I'm using suggestion from the comment there, still didn't work

Comment: why is `diff` 3? wouldn't the difference be 4 days?

Comment: To be sure, `np.busday_count('2022-08-01','2022-08-05')` would result in `4`, not `3`. Similarly, `np.busday_count('2022-08-20','2022-08-28')` == `5`, not `8`. Please confirm that you are looking for *business days*.

Comment: "I want to have another column which tells the difference in days" difference in days, or in business days?

Comment: What if `date_1` is empty but `date_2` is not? Should it give `0` or `empty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to coerce the types. Also, better to avoid lambdas if you have more than one condition to check. Code below runnable as-is, though the second diff value will change if you run it tomorrow :)

```py
def busday_diff(x):
    if pd.isna(x.date_1):
        return ""
    date2_to_use = pd.Timestamp("today") if pd.isna(x.date_2) else x.date_2
    return np.busday_count(np.datetime64(x.date_1, "D"), np.datetime64(date2_to_use, "D"))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date_1": ["2022-08-01", "2022-08-20", np.nan], "date_2": ["2022-08-05", np.nan, np.nan]}
)

df["diff"] = df.apply(busday_diff, axis=1)

​
print(df)

#      date_1     date_2 diff
#0 2022-08-01 2022-08-05    4
#1 2022-08-20        NaT    5 
#2        NaT        NaT
```

If you have to do more than a couple of these, you will probably want to vectorize it. Pandas and Numpy are much much faster if you can vectorize your commands:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_1": ["2022-08-01", "2022-08-20", np.nan, np.nan],
        "date_2": ["2022-08-05", np.nan, np.nan, "2022-08-10"],
    }
)
calcable = df[~df.date_1.isnull()].fillna(pd.Timestamp("today").date())[["date_1", "date_2"]]

df["diff"] = pd.Series(
    np.busday_count(
        calcable.date_1.values.astype("datetime64[D]"),
        calcable.date_2.values.astype("datetime64[D]"),
    ),
    index=calcable.index,
)
```

Interestingly, the cast to "D" resolution *must* be called on the underlying numpy array `values`. Otherwise it reverts back to "ns" resolution. This is probably the origin of the confusion behind this question. Strange design decision on the part of pandas:

```py
calcable.date_1.values.astype("datetime64[D]")

# array(['2022-08-01', '2022-08-20'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

calcable.date_1.astype("datetime64[D]").values

# array(['2022-08-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2022-08-20T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have another column which tells the difference in days

If you just want days:

```
df.assign(
    diff=lambda df: (
        pd.to_datetime(df["date_2"]).fillna(pd.Timestamp.now())
        - pd.to_datetime(df["date_1"])
    ).dt.days
)
```

which outputs

```
       date_1      date_2  diff
0  2022-08-01  2022-08-05   4.0
1  2022-08-20         NaN   8.0
2         NaN         NaN   NaN
```

EDIT: it was later clarified that they want business days, so please refer to the other answer instead

Comment: It works but i will need to get only the difference in using business days (Monday-Friday). FYI, i didn't downvote you. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the OP is *claiming* to request *business days*. Now, *if* it turns out that s/he is simply looking for the difference in all days, I'll happily delete that downvote again. But until that matter is cleared up, your answer is premature at best (and wrong at worse).

Comment: @ouroboros1 the question says "I want to have another column which tells the difference in days", not "in business days", so that's what I answered

Comment: Well, the OP just clarified. I grant that the question is ambiguous, but that's why I said your answer is premature. If the OP wasn't looking for business days, why else would s/he want to use `np.busday_count`? Also, the expected output is wrong in either case. The OP was assuming `3 and 8`, which (as you correctly show) would be `4 and 8` for normal day diff.